# IO and EOF Exception on sending and receiving byte to and from server

Tags: android, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I am trying to create a server and client application on two android Phone(Nexus 4).One Phone as client and other as server. But at the server side I am getting an error of EOF exception while reading the incoming data and at the client side I am getting IO exception while writing some byte to Socket outputStream. Can someone enlighten me what I am doing wrong?

Client side Code

```
       // Send only one byte to server

  while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

        try {

            Log.d(TAG,"Entering into the IO exception block");
            byte[] image_data = new byte[3];
            String send_string = new String(image_data);

            // Create a Output Stream to send the bytes back to server 
            OutputStream out;

            out = s.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
            Log.d(TAG,"Created data output Stream");


            dos.writeUTF(send_string);

            /*
            dos.writeInt(image_data.length);
            dos.write(image_data, 0, image_data.length);
            Log.d(TAG,"Writing the ByteArray into Socket ");
            */

            out.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            s.close();


        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Exception while writing to Socket");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


   }
```

Server side Code :  Exception while dis.readFully(ClientByteArray)

```
   if (s == null)
                s = ss.accept();

            Log.d(TAG,"Socket server is closed " + ss.isClosed() +", Recieved Buffer Size = " + ss.getReceiveBufferSize());
            Log.d(TAG,"Accepted Client socket at server");

            byte[] ClientByteArray = new byte[ss.getReceiveBufferSize()];

            InputStream in;
            in = s.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
    dis.readFully(ClientByteArray);

            Log.d(TAG,"Data recieved from Client, Bytes = " + ClientByteArray.length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing with `writeUTF()`, so you should be reading with `readUTF()`.